# Mysqldump confusion?

Tags: database, mysql

- If i will lock my tables while taking
  dump of production and at the same
  time if user will enter any data for
  specific table. What will happen to
  that specific insertion ? Will it be
  discarded or it will be inserted
  after successful creation of dump ?
- If i will not lock my tables while
  taking dump of production. Will it
  create any problem ?
- Which one is preferred way to taking
  dump of production with or without
  locking tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use mysqldump to backup your tables and someone attempts to modify the locked table, their update will block until the table is unlocked by mysqldump.
- If you do not lock your tables while attempting to make a backup, it is entirely possible your backup would end up in an inconsistent state.  Depending on your application, it could cause problems.
- As @tsykoduk states, it is best to take your backups from a read-only replica of your production server.  If that's not possible, the best solution depends on your environment.  For example, if you use only InnoDB tables, you can run mysqldump with `--single-transaction` to ensure a consistent backup without blocking updates.

The MySQL docs describe most of these options in greater detail:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I have only InnoDB. So, i don't need to worry about lock and all that ? Why ? What will --single-transaction do?

Comment: The full description can be found here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction

Comment: But basically it starts a transaction, creates the dump, than closes the transaction.  That way mysqldump sees a consistent view of what the DB looked like when the transaction began, but the table continues to get updated outside of that transaction.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to take a backup off of a read-only replica, as when you lock the tables, any writes will error out. Also, a backup can be a pretty resource intensive operation, so it can effect performance.

If you do not have a read-only replica, then I would suggest looking into one of the MySQL hot backup products out there (Percona has a good [one](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start), as I recall).

Also - if you do not lock the tables, or use a hot backup product, you run the risk of not getting a complete backup. IE, if someone is writing to a table, and has it locked when you run the backup, you'll get corrupted data.